# will_paginate -ActionView::Template::Error variable appears to be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm trying to implement a simple index page for one on my models that uses the will_paginate gem. (Rails 3) and am receiving the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (The @load_verifications variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?)

My code is the same (as far as I can tell) as all the other index pages I'm using will_paginate on that work.

LoadVerificationsController.rb:

```
def index
@loadVerifications = LoadVerification.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order('ship_date')

end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Loads')%>
<h1>All Loads</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul>
<%= render @loadVerifications %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

_load_verification.html.erb:

```
<li>
<%= loadVerification.sales_order %>
<%= loadVerification.ship_date %>
<%= loadVerification.pallet_count %>
 <%= link_to "view", loadVerification %>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure where the @load_verification variable referenced in the error message comes from since I haven't declared it in the controller and the variable I'm using is @loadVerification (no underscore). I will also mention that I don't currently have any data in the LoadVerifications table, but I would think that will_paginate is smart enough to handle an empty result set without throwing exceptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [official will_paginate gem documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#will_paginatecollection-options) says: you should pass your collection (`@loadVerifications` in your case) as a parameter to `will_paginate` view helper:

```
<%= will_paginate @loadVerifications %>
```

Here's the source code which raises this error.

[method call](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb#L28) from within `will_paginate` method.

[method declaration](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb#L91).

Briefly: if no collection is given to `will_paginate` helper, it tries to build instance variable's name from controller's name

Comment: Life saver! I didn't realize it was naming the object by the controller name.